# Prop is undefined when passed to functional component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to include PrintGrid functional component in my LoadGridData component. The PrintGrid should receive a document_id of firebase from LoadGridData. But inside the return statement of the LoadGridData, I try to pass the grid_id which is in a grid_data list to PrintGrid and it causes grid_id value to be undefined.

```
function PrintGrid(grid_id) {
  console.log('Print grid_id in PrintGrid: ', grid_id);
```

The below gives an error that it cannot access index 0 of undefined.

```
{grid_data && <PrintGrid grid_id={grid_data[0]} />}
```

With only the following statement, it updates the grid_data[0] value (grid_id) to the webpage.

```
{grid_data && <p> {grid_data[0]} </p>}
```

Comment: I see an error in `function PrintGrid` definition - the argument `grid_id` should be enclosed in `{ }` - i.e. `function PrintGrid({ grid_id })` (so that the `props` are deconstructed into the `grid_id`). However, that should not be causing the other problem. Please provide more code. The `LoadGridData` code. Also, the connection of `document_id` to the rest is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing the props object and just passing grid_id direct to PrintGrind function

Change

```
function PrintGrid(grid_id) {
```

to

```
function PrintGrid({grid_id}) {
```

The above is the ES6 way of de-structuring objects and getting fields within directly.

You could also just do PrintGrid(props) and inside the function access props.grid_id

```
function PrintGrid(props) {  
    console.log(props.grid_id)
}
```